# Looking for single regex that can "toggle" between two states

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Looking for some creative ideas. This is for javascript-flavored regular expressions.

When I say "toggle", I mean a single regex and single capture-referencing-replacement-string that can do the following:

```
'my-on-state'.replace(/MYSTERY/, '???')   // => 'my-off-state'
'my-off-state'.replace(/MYSTERY/, '???')   // => 'my-on-state'
```

Given an if and two regexes, this would be trivial; with just 1 regex, though, I'm not sure how it could be done without some way to "capture" a group that doesn't actually exist in the source text -- is there some way to do this, perhaps using a lookahead capture?

(For those wondering: this is not actual javascript code, it's for a VSCode keybinding argument; you're allowed a single regex-and-replace in a variable reference, so I've got to cram whatever I can into that single regex.)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Are you switching the two values or changing the `on` to `off` or vice-versa? If that's the case, what are the rules? Are there other words that need to be replaced? When you say only one regex replace, do you mean you want to combine your two regular expressions into one? If that's the case, it's not possible with javascript's regex unless you use a callback function.

Comment: Well, there's a bunch of text before and after this snippet that I care about, but it's not interesting/relevant (ie it has straightforward solutions).  Probably you could boil my question down to "is there a single regex and replace statement that replaces the string 'apple' with 'banana' and 'banana' with 'apple'".

Comment: Does this help? ConditionalReplace :http://www.rexegg.com/regex-trick-conditional-replacement.html .You'd need to replace it to be ('my-on-state' + 'onoff').replace(...) then

Comment: Perhaps like this: https://jsfiddle.net/z9854b5y/

Comment: Thanks for suggestions all, I think what I was trying to do can't be done with one regex (it can definitely be done with two, or with matches + if statements, etc.).  Luckily I've found another way to solve the problem.

Comment: Old question, but are you trying to do this running in code or in an editor?  If in an editor like vscode, it is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "you could boil my question down to "is there a single regex and
> replace statement that replaces the string 'apple' with 'banana' and
> 'banana' with 'apple'"

> "it's for a VSCode keybinding argument"

You don't explain in great detail but it sounds like you need a conditional replacement - and you can do those in vscode snippets:

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+y",                        // whatever keybinding you like
  "command":  "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(apple)|(banana)/${1:+banana}${2:+apple}/g}"

        // if you would rather leave the snippet in a snippet file use this version 
        //  and the snippet that follows below
    // "name": "Apple <=> Banana"  

  },

  // "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
},
```

or

```
"Apple <=> Banana": {
 "prefix": "a-b",
  "body": [
    "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(apple)|(banana)/${1:+banana}${2:+apple}/g}"
  ],
  "description": "apples to bananas"
}
```

[image: demo of conditional replacement]

Comment: I think where I was headed was more about file switching (for example, auto-opening /spec/foo-spec.js if editing /src/foo.js, and vice versa).  But the "when" trick you used would work equally well for that (I suppose by matching `resource` against a resource, and then using `$TM_FILENAME` in the action... if I can figure out what action would actually open a file and not a file picker or dialog window.)

Comment: How can you select text and then type a snippet prefix and still have the text in the editor selected?

Comment: You cannot, hence the keybinding.  But people may still prefer to have the snippet in a snippet and then reference the snippet name through the keybinding - keeping all snippets in a snippet file rather than some sprinkled throughout the keybindings.  I just didn't show the snippet name version.  I'll add it later.